# Read all files in specific folder in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read all files in a specific sub-folder of the `wd`. I have been able to add a `for` loop successfully, but the loop only looks at files within the `wd`. I thought the command line:

`directory <- 'folder.I.want.to.look.in'`

would enable this but the script still only looks in the `wd`. However, the above command does help create a list of the correct files. I have included the script below that I have written but not sure what I need to modify to aim it at a specific sub-folder.

```
directory <- 'folder.I.want.to.look.in'
files <- list.files(path = directory)
out_file <- read_excel("file.to.be.used.in.output", col_names = TRUE)

for (filename in files){
  
  show(filename)
  
  filepath <- paste0(filename)
  

  ## Import data
  data <- read_excel(filepath, skip = 8, col_names = TRUE)
  data <- data[, -c(6:8)]
further script
}
```

The `further script` is irrelevant to this question and works fine. I just can't get the loop to look over each file in `files` from `directory`. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `list.files(..., recursive = TRUE)`?

Comment: Just added this and tried but same result. At the end of the loop I get - Error: 'path' does not exist: '2nd.file.in.files.xlsx'. That tells me it's still aimed at the working directory and not the folder I want to look at (I moved a file to the wd to check).

Comment: `list.files(..., full.names = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your base directory, and then use it to create a vector of all the files with `list.files`, e.g.:

```
base_dir <- 'path/to/my/working/directory'
all_files <- paste0(base_dir, list.files(base_dir, recursive = TRUE))
```

Then just loop over `all_files`. By default, `list.files` has `recursive = FALSE`, i.e., it will only get the files and directory names of the directory you specify, rather than going into each subfolder. Setting `recursive = TRUE` will return the full filepath excluding your base directory, which is why we concatenate it with `base_dir`.

Comment: Worked well. Thanks for the help!